# Doctrine always filter rows with certain column values

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using Symfony 5.1 with doctrine. I would like to know how to put a filter on a field/column for all doctrine queries that do a search on an entity. For example, with the entity Sejour I would like to make sure all queries that search for this entity have the where by clause on the field/column: "sejAnnule != 'Y'". Here is the Sejour entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use DateTime;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Sejour.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Sejour")})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SejourRepository")
 */
class Sejour
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="SEJ_NO", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private int $sejNo;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="SEJ_ANNULE", type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
     */
    private string $sejAnnule;

    public function getSejAnnule(): ?string
    {
        return $this->sejAnnule;
    }

    public function setSejAnnule(?string $sejAnnule): void
    {
        $this->sejAnnule = $sejAnnule;
    }
    
        public function getSejNo(): int
    {
        return $this->sejNo;
    }

    public function setSejNo(int $sejNo): void
    {
        $this->sejNo = $sejNo;
    }
}
```

I think this is possible with doctrine filters but I was wondering if anyone knows a quicker way to do this (e.g. an annotation on the field or a bundle)?

Comment: I think this is conceptually risky and not advisable (both doctrine filters as well as an "annotation" or something). add a repository function instead.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to this I think is to use a doctrine filter. No need to create an event listener (as i first thought). Create the filter:

```
<?php

namespace App\Filter;

use App\Entity\Sejour;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Filter\SQLFilter;

class SoftDeleteFilter extends SQLFilter
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {

        if (Sejour::class == $targetEntity->getReflectionClass()->name) {
            return sprintf(' %s.SEJ_ANNULE  != \'Y\'', $targetTableAlias);
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

Then enable the filter in doctrine.yaml:

```
orm:
    filters:
        soft_delete_filter:
            class: AppBundle\Doctrine\SoftDeleteFilter 
            enabled: true
```

Symfony documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/configuration.html#filters-configuration

The Symfony Casts documentation (although this is with an event listener) https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-queries/filters

Comment: Using the event listener allows you to enable/disable the filter and pass additional settings to the parameter from different parts of the project.